# Control home WiFi switches from office

Tags: smart-home, smart-plugs

What kind of setup is required to control Home Fan, Lights, AC, Computers from outside home.

First thing I'll need is static IP address to reach the Home LAN. Next for computers, I can setup wake on LAN.

How would I connect and control the power switches of FAN, Lights, AC? Can standard wifi smart plugs be controlled from internet?

Thanks.

Comment: Some (probably most) smart plugs can (either directly or through a Hub). You usually don't even need a static IP for that, the switch or plug will connect to a cloud server, and you will connect to that (usually with an app). You'd need to check for specific models/brands, though, as the details may vary quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done with existing IOT module and I have done for my home with ESP8266 via blynk App.
What you need:

1. ESP8266 module Version 01S is already okay for controlling 4 relays (4 devices).
2. 4 relays board
   [https://www.amazon.com/JBtek-Channel-Module-Arduino-Raspberry/dp/B00KTEN3TM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KTEN3TM)

or this:
https://cf.shopee.vn/file/b5850e5a9f9becf17b59f2ba4b5441a6
What you need is a power module and install Blynk app and work a bit on creating project, connecting to the esp8266, set it up and have your stuff run!

Comment: Just to mention, blynk is only free for up to five devices and for personal use.

Comment: I installed blynk server at home and dont really see this limitation. I will check to see if this would be a case!
Thanks @Helmar

Answer (score 1):

The methodology behind this smart home automation and control is , you need a relay and microcontroller to control your home appliances and with that you can control by passing inputs to your microcontroller at the same way , you have to pass the values to microcontroller through protocol , as your post you have chosen wifi as your protocol , now you have to pass the particular input to that protocol , for that you have to write a server socket programming and you have to pass this input from your particular API , creating your own API helps you to control securely ,. This is the mechanism behind smart home